# Get css properties from one element and apply to another

Tags: jquery

**css:**

```
#foo1 { color: #FFF; border: 1px solid #000; }
```

**html:**

```
<div id="foo1"></div>
<div id="foo2"></div>
```

**js:**

I know that i can fetch the values one by one using css keys, but is there any way to get all the css properties at once, and apply the values. Something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#foo2').css($('#foo1').css());
});
```

Comment: This question is repeated, check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element

Answer (score 4):

You could make the style into a class and then just use addClass to apply the style to the second div.

```
.foo-style { color: #FFF; border: 1px solid #000; }

<div id="foo1" class="foo-style"></div>
<div id="foo2"></div>

$(function(){
   $('#foo2').addClass('foo-style');
});
```

Comment: Yes but im asking for a way to get the css properties from an element as an object. Sorry for being unclear

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work in jsfiddle, but I would have expected it to work for inline styles only in the wild, but have'nt tested it outside jsFiddle:

```
$("#foo2").css('cssText', $("#foo1").css('cssText'));
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6hfXU/1/)

Comment: Yes, but i tried to mentioned that I already know that: "I know that i can fetch the values one by one using css keys" :)

Comment: @Johan - Did you notice that it actually fetches ALL the CSS values, and not just one by one ?